# Unable to access variable from 1 file to other file without executing code in first file

Tags: python, global-variables

I need my variable to be passed from 1 file to other file without executing first file after importing module.

I tried using global but still of no use.

test.py

```
import random

r1='test'
def main():
    global r1
    r1 = random.randint(0, 10000)
    print(r1)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
else:
    print(r1)
```

test1.py

```
import test

print(test.r1)
```

when i execute test.py i got 1012 as output and i expect same output when i run it from test1.py. This is chaining program, so i want to execute test.py and r1 variable should be passed to test1.py somehow with out executing test.py from test1.py. Ideally test1.py should use output created by test.py

Comment: Are you expecting `test.r1` to have a random value when you call it in `test1.py`?

Comment: No. I will execute test.py once and should be able to access same value in test1.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python modules are structured similar to classes, so when a module is imported, the code will run as you can see with a class in this example

```py
class MyClass:
    a = print('exe')
```

Note that the class variable `a` gets assigned, and therefore statement `print` gets executed right after class definition is completed.
I don't see how this would be necessary, but if you need to have the same value of `random.random()` imported from the first file, you should create a text file, which will act as a variable and thus you can save and read the values from it.

Comment: I feel thats the only option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want `r1` to be persistent, your best solution is to save it into a file that you can access from `test1.py` when you need to. If all you need is a random int and you must get it from another python script, you could simply define a function inside `test.py` and call it from `test1.py`. It would look something like this:

```
import random

def getRandInt():
    r1 = random.randint(0, 10000)
    return r1

def main():
    print(getRandInt())


if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

and you can call from another script with:

```
import test

r1 = test.getRandInt()
print(r1)
```

Note that if you do this and you run `test.py` and then run `test1.py` the random int will be different. This is because after a script is done executing, the memory that it used to store variables and such is reclaimed by the OS for something else.